# Apache Tomcat: adding/deleting/editing JNDI resources

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

Is there a facility in Tomcat (version 6) to add/delete/edit JNDI resources?  If it's possible, how would I update a JDBC data source (as an example)?
Note that I'm looking for a possibility to update a JNDI resource *without* redeploying an application.
Apparently Glassfish let's you do this, unfortunately using another application server is currently not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat does not let you bind new elements to the JNDI tree after boot. You should be able to change their properties using the admin console.